# How to filter different data (parameters) in an easy way in Access?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I’m an architect living in Sweden and I work in Autodesk Revit.
We export data from Revit to Excel.
I have just started to work with access and use it to import 
data from three different Revit models (as Excel)  to Access and 
create a pdf report from there.
What I would like to have help with is that 
we need to be able to filter information very easily
so that we can work with different parameters at the same time!
There is something called "Schedules" in Revit there you can see
different parameters but it’s very hard to filter.
We would like to for example see all the doors in all 
operation rooms in plan 4 that have a certain color and so on!
My question is: is there an easy way to filter information easily in Access or 
Excel? 
I have worked with a database there they used Manga and it 
Worked great but I would like to make my own database using Access.
Would be very grateful if you could help me:)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Doing this sort of filtering with a database (Access, MySQL, etc.) is super-simple. One you create the table(s) and enter the data, you can do something like:

```
select
   r.room_name,
   r.room_id,
   r.room_location
from ROOMS r
   where r.color = 'red'
```

This is the type of operation databases were designed for.

Comment: Yes, but I want to filter different parameters( we have like 20) and see the relationship between them!

Comment: You can add additional constraints, like select
   r.room_name,
   r.room_id,
   r.room_location
from ROOMS r
   where r.color = 'red' and r.number_of_doors = 3 and r.number_of_chairs = 16      That would return a row for each room that matches those parameters.

Comment: You can also search for patterns that *don't* match a certain value, so you could do something like r.number_of_chairs != 16 to find rooms that don't have 16 chairs. SQL is extremely powerful and flexible for finding exactly the information you're looking for.